# how to make vertx-node socket server accept the request from the WebSocket

Tags: node.js, react-native, vert.x

I'm sending the request from the react-native to vertx-server through WebSocket

```
    socket = New WebSocket(url);
```

socket hitting the vertx server,

```
    var server = vertx.createNetServer();
    server.connectHandler(function (
      socket.write("Hello subbbu World!\n");
      socket.close();
    });

    server.listen(3000);
```

But on the react-native side socket is closing, I mean

```
    socket.onopen = () => {
        function not calling
    }
```

Help me with this, if socket is open, then only i can send something to server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you used does not start a websocket server, just a raw TCP server.

To start a websocket server, you should do:

```
vertx.createHttpServer().websocketHandler(function (ws) {
  // Do something with the incoming websocket
}).listen(8080);
```

More info in the [Websockets](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/js/#_websockets) section of the Vert.x docs.